# Plotly: How to use two color scales in a single plotly map figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to plot a scatter_mapbox plot over a choropleth_mapbox plot using plotly. I want to use Picnic for the scatter_mapbox plot's color scale. When I run this, the scatter_mapbox colorscale is set to the same properties as the choropleth_mapbox properties. Namely, it uses the color scale Viridis instead of Picnic and uses the choropleth's numerical scale. How can I make the the colorscale for the scatterplot Picnic.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

df = px.data.election()
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    px.data.election_geojson()["features"]
).merge(df, on="district").set_index("district")
df = df.loc[df['geometry'].map(lambda x: type(x) == shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)]
df2 = df.copy()
df2['geometry'] = df2['geometry'].map(lambda x: x.exterior.coords[0]).map(shapely.geometry.Point)


#make the charts
map_fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df, 
    geojson=df.geometry, 
    locations=df.index, 
    color='Bergeron',
    center= { 'lon': df2.geometry.x.iloc[0], 'lat': df2.geometry.y.iloc[0]}, 
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    opacity = 0.2,
)

map_fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df2,
    lat=df2.geometry.y,
    lon=df2.geometry.x,
    size='Bergeron',
    zoom=12,
    color='Bergeron', color_continuous_scale='Picnic', 
    opacity = 1, 
    size_max=10
)

map_fig.add_trace(map_fig2.data[0])
map_fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)


map_fig.show()
```

A step in the right direction is to add this, which puts the scatter_mapbox on a separate coloraxis, but sets the color scale to the plotly default, Plasma, instead of Picnic, as specified. It also overlays the colorbar.

```
    'color' : np.array(df2['Bergeron']),
    'coloraxis' : 'coloraxis2',
    'opacity' : 1,
    'colorscale' : 'Picnic',
    'sizemode' : 'area',
    'sizeref' : .01,
    'autocolorscale' : False
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! If you found my suggestion sufficiently useful, please consider an up-vote as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you're aiming to do:

[image]

Then follow these steps in addition to what you're already doing:

**1.** Steal the coloraxis from `fig2` where `color='Picnic'` to `fig` with:

```
fig.layout.coloraxis2 = fig2.layout.coloraxis
```

**2.** Include the second trace with:

```
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])
```

**3.** Assign colors to the second trace with:

```
fig['data'][1]['marker'] = {    'color' : np.array(df2['Bergeron']),
                                    'coloraxis' : 'coloraxis2',
                                }
```

**4.** Move the second colorbar to a more suitable place with:

```
fig.layout.coloraxis2.colorbar.x = -0.2
```

The third step makes the colors for the second trace available through `'coloraxis' : 'coloraxis2'`

I hope this is what you were looking for. Don't hesitate to let me know if not!

#### Complete code:

*(Sorry, I got tired of typing `map_fig` so I change the references to merely `fig`)*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

df = px.data.election()
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    px.data.election_geojson()["features"]
).merge(df, on="district").set_index("district")
df = df.loc[df['geometry'].map(lambda x: type(x) == shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon)]
df2 = df.copy()
df2['geometry'] = df2['geometry'].map(lambda x: x.exterior.coords[0]).map(shapely.geometry.Point)


#make the charts
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df, 
    geojson=df.geometry, 
    locations=df.index, 
    color='Bergeron',
    center= { 'lon': df2.geometry.x.iloc[0], 'lat': df2.geometry.y.iloc[0]}, 
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    opacity = 0.2,
)

fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df2,
    lat=df2.geometry.y,
    lon=df2.geometry.x,
    size='Bergeron',
    zoom=12,
    color='Bergeron',
    color_continuous_scale='picnic',
    opacity = 1, 
    size_max=10
)

fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])
fig.layout.coloraxis2 = fig2.layout.coloraxis
fig['data'][1]['marker'] = {    'color' : np.array(df2['Bergeron']),
                                    'coloraxis' : 'coloraxis2',
                                    'opacity' : 1,
                                    'sizemode' : 'area',
                                    'sizeref' : .01,
                                    'autocolorscale' : False
                                }

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.layout.coloraxis2.colorbar.x = -0.2
fig.show()
```